# GeoServer WMS username / password issue for external requests

Tags: wms, authentication

I am having a problem with WMS services when accessing my GeoServer from outside of the intranet and requiring basic username and password authentication. I am accessing the GeoServer with a URL which creates a 'tunnel' to the GeoServer IP and port.

The WCS, WFS and WMTS all work fine but WMS will only expose the availbale layers in QGIS and when any of the layers are added to the map the data is not displayed.

If I use QGIS from within the intranet and use the GeoServer IP address then all of the protocols, incl. WMS work fine (with username and password included).

If I enable anonymous read permissions then the external accessed WMS works fine.

It thus seems that the authentication is only problematic for external WMS requests to the GeoServer (with WCS, WFS and WMTS all working without problem).

Any ideas on what may be causing this issue for WMS?

Comment: do you use a proxy server for external users?

Comment: We are using a Cloudflared tunnel to connect the public hostname to our internal GeoGerver IP:port.
No proxies are being used.